# Как правильно записывать в БД Hibernate со связками(изучаю hibernate)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, hibernate

Не получаеться найти информацию о правильной записи со связками
сайт hibernate у меня висит и не открывается

Есть два Entity

parent :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "userEntity")
    private List<LikesEntity> likesEntities;

    public List<LikesEntity> getLikesEntities() {
        return likesEntities;
    }

    public void setLikesEntities(List<LikesEntity> likesEntities) {
        this.likesEntities = likesEntities;
    }

    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")//Автоматическая генерация ID
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private long id;

    private long fbId;

    private int gender;

    private boolean active;
    private boolean authenticate;

    @Id
    private String email;
}
```

и child:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private UserEntity userEntity;

private String whoLike;
```

Пытаясь создать функцию "лайков"

написал следующее

```
public boolean doLike(String mail) {
    //вытягиваю из БД юзера с List<Лайков>
    UserEntity userEntity = entityManager.find(UserEntity.class, mail);
    // проверяю не пустой ли этот лист
    if (!userEntity.getLikesEntities().isEmpty()) {
        for (LikesEntity likeEntity : userEntity.getLikesEntities()) {               //ищу нет ли "моего" лайка
            if (likeEntity.getWhoLike().equals(user.getEmail())) return false;
        }
    }

    LikesEntity like = new LikesEntity();
    //добавляю себя в "лайкающие"
    like.setWhoLike(user.getEmail());
    userEntity.getLikesEntities().add(like); //добавляю в лист "нового лайкающего"
    entityManager.merge(userEntity); // тут падаю при попытке переписать -> 18:52:20,896 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-37) UT005023: Exception handling request to /secured/main.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)

    return true;
}
```

Подскажите что не правильно или где почитать,
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Чтобы лайки сохранялись каскадно нужно добавить каскадное сохранение у аннотации `@OneToMany` (сейчас у вас стоит только `CascadeType.REMOVE`)
2. У новой сущности `LikesEntity` необходимо проставить родителя - `UserEntity`
3. Ваша ошибка при сохранении связана с отсутствием транзакции - перед вызовом `merge` нужно ее начать, а после - закоммитить ([аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084627/entitymanager-throws-transactionrequiredexception-on-merge-in-jboss-jsf-bean)).

Comment: Можно ли немного подробней ?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

использовал 

@Resource
UserTransaction ut;

Но так и не понял как поставить родителя...

Если Вам не сложно, то, пожалуйста, опишите подробней

Comment: like.setUserEntity(userEntity);

Comment: Аааа... так и сделал :) думал аннотация есть, которую не смог найти